# MySQL Restore Slows Down Server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a database that is around 100GB big and I dumped the file using mysqldump and gzip using the following command.

> mysqldump --single-transaction --triggers --routines -uroot -pPASS
>   DBNAME | gzip > E:\Backups\DBNAME.sql.gz

I am trying to restore the database onto a test server that is being used by other developers and testers in the company and the server is slowing down until it is almost unusable. Below is the restore command.

> gzip -v -d < E:\DBNAME.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -pPASS DBNAME

How can I restore this large database onto a server without mysql restore using up all the resources?

How do people do this on a LIVE server without affecting performance?

**DB Version: MariaDB 10.2**

**Table Engine: InnoDB**

Thanks

Comment: Two steps: First extract the file...and then restore the file with `mysql -uroot -p databasename < thedatabasefile.sql`

Comment: Are you extracting on the same machine?  Into the same instance of MariaDB??  (I hope not.)

Comment: I'm backing up from server 1, copying the gzip file to server 2 and running the extract / restore command on server 2. Server 1 has is a mariadb 10.1 instance and server 2 is a 10.2 instance. Why is it better to extract first then restore? Thanks.